# Reason for tampering of bitband mapping address at run time

Tags: arm, embedded, cortex-m, keil

I am using bit banding to set and clear a GPIO6[1] of LPC1857 using Keil.

The mapping address in bit band region to **set** GPIO6[1] comes **0x43EC4304**

The mapping address in bit band region to **clear** GPIO6[1] comes **0x43EC5384**

THE GPIO gets set successfully but does not get cleared.

When checked on debugger, it is observed that mapping address to clear the GPIO6[1] was getting set to **0x43EC5000**. Thus the GPIO does not get clear.

Can someone please help understand why this is happening ?
And how can I resolve this mapping address setting to wrong address at run time ?

Following is code snippet:

```
/*In "main.c"*/

int main()
{
    ... //System initialization
    ... //GPIO init
    ...


    Toggle_Peri();
}


/*In "Peri.c"*/


/* Bit band PERIPHERAL definitions */

#define BITBAND_PERI_REF     0x40000000 //Start Address of PeripheRALS
#define BITBAND_PERI_BASE    0x42000000 //Start Address of Peripheral Bit Band Alias Region

/* Basic bit band function definition */
#define BITBAND_PERI(a,b) ((BITBAND_PERI_BASE + ((a-BITBAND_PERI_REF)*(0x20)) + (b*(0x04))))  // Convert GPIO address

#define BITBAND_PERI_SetClearBit(a,b)   ((*(volatile uint32_t *) (BITBAND_PERI(a,b))) = 1)

/*Note: Base Address of GPIO       =  0x400F 4000*/
#define PERI_GPIO_ADDRESS_S 0x400F6218 //For GPIO6[1] set
#define PERI_GPIO_ADDRESS_C 0x400F629C //For GPIO6[1] clear
#define PERI_GPIO_BIT       1 

...
...
...
...

void Toggle_Peri(void)
{
    BITBAND_PERI_SetClearBit(PERI_GPIO_ADDRESS_S,PERI_GPIO_BIT);    //Set the pin
    Delay(0xFFFF);  
    BITBAND_PERI_SetClearBit(PERI_GPIO_ADDRESS_C,PERI_GPIO_BIT);    //Clear the pin
    Delay(0xFFFF);
}
```

Comment: All integer literals should be defined with `ul` for unsigned long. e.g. `0x40000000ul`

Comment: @Rishi Thanks. done that.

Comment: Given that there are separate set and clear registers avoiding a non-atomic read-modify-write, what is the purpose of using bit-banding here in any case?

Comment: @Clifford: It is for delay compensation for bit banging I2C protocol.

Comment: @SonamKhullar : No, I meant what is the advantage over simply writing the appropriate bit mask to the respective get/set registers.

Comment: Well, compiling the code presented here results in literally `ldr r3, =0x43ec5384; mov r2, #1; str r2, [r3]...`, so assuming you're running from flash (or the literal pool is otherwise read-only via the MPU) there's only a teeny-tiny window for runtime corruption there. If you have any interrupts active I'd have a strong suspicion there's some broken code in an IRQ handler somewhere.

Comment: Hang on, looking at the TRM, 0x400F629C is **CLR7** - no wonder it doesn't affect port 6...

Comment: @Notlikethat: Yes code is running from the flash.Only UART interrupt is active.Thing is CLR6 gets affected well by the CMSIS library code but I see corruption at bit banding implementation for same. So what is your observation?Is it that its chip fault or something that i need to do more in code/compiler setting?

Comment: Oh! Ok I get it.So it was a silly silly mistake! But yet the corruption is happening.Need to look for it.

Comment: So if you write to the correct register the pin turns off as expected? In that case the "corruption" is almost certainly a red herring: unless you're instruction-stepping through the disassembly and looking at the actual register contents, then anything a debugger says about the (source-level) program state can be considered at best approximate. Even more so for code compiled with a reasonable level of optimisation.

Comment: @Notlikethat Yes I checked it the pin is getting turned off as expected. I shall keep in mind thing about debugger you mentioned above.Thanks.